# Develop an application that uses the Julius Caesar cipher with keys greater than 1

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

given a text i have to encrypt it and decrypt it with Caesar method. A user will give a key and this key could have more than 4 digit. to cipher the text each digit must have it table.

example:

text=don't touch my spaghetti
key=1234  //this key has to be divided like [1,2,3,4]

to cipher the text, every character has to be shift with one of these numbers

example:
the character "d" will be shift with 1, "o" will be shift with 2, "n" will be shift with 3 , "t" will be shift with 4 and this will repeat till the text has been encrypted of decrypted.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] ... and accept our congratulations for the task :). No, seriously: What is your question? What have you tried? You've basically described the approach already so what's the problem?

Comment: OT: if the key if larger than 1, it is no longer a Caesar cipher but a [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher)

Comment: Why not develop it yourself?

Comment: i didn't get the result i wanted for some reason

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you are looking for isn't a Caesar Cipher anymore, but alright then.

here's some guidance:

- Convert input to array.
- Iterate for each in input array: apply basic ceasar cipher with the corresponding shift and add to output array. //to get the right shift, Get the current index of the iteration, devide it by the size of the key, and get the remainder (Modulus Operation)
- Convert output array to string.